# Oracle SQL: find the most common surname by state

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying to answer this seemingly easy question but am stuck

I have two tables containing information for 7M individuals, one contains name [including surname] information, the other address [including state] information. These are joined on an id

I want to find the most common surname for each state. So I want to return a list as follows, ordered by state alphabetically with count for most common name

```
:State:     :Name:      :Count:
State A     Planck       5789                                        
State B     Heisenberg   8412 
State C     Dirac        2178
```

Seems like it should be easy but I'm getting bogged down, thanks in advance!

Comment: you should provide the statements to generate the tables and test data.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
select state, name, cnt
from (select state, name, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by state order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by state, name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This uses `rank()` so it will return multiple rows if there are ties for first place.  Use `row_number()` if you want to return one arbitrary row in the event of ties.

Comment: If you group by state. do you need partition by state?

Comment: thanks a million, very elegant.
I wasn't too far off it but still wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, yes, the `PARTITION BY` is necessary, otherwise the query will return only one state's values instead of returning the most common surname by state.

Answer (score 1):

You need `GROUP BY` :

```
select t.state, t.name, t.count
from (select State, Name, count(*) as count
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seq
      from table 
      group by State, Name
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: thanks Yogesh, I tried the same thing but the result was a bit of a mess of names and states.

Comment: This will return only one state, rather than returning the most common surname per state.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to apply `UPPER()` or possibly `INITCAP()` to the surname before grouping on it to get a count, unless you want variations in case (e.g., `McDonald` vs. `Mcdonald`) to be distinguished:

```
SELECT state, MAX(surname_cnt) AS surname_cnt
     , MAX(surname) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY surname_cnt DESC ) AS most_popular_surname
  FROM (
    SELECT state, INITCAP(surname) AS surname, COUNT(*) AS surname_cnt
      FROM mytable
     GROUP BY state, INITCAP(surname)
) GROUP BY state;
```

Hope this helps.